# Why does halite have perfect cleavage at the (110) plane?

Tags: crystals, mineralogy, crystallography

Why doesn't it cleave nicely along the (100) or (010) or any other planes? What determines its cleavage plane? I know it has something to do with the fact that it crystallizes in face centered cubic  system but I don't understand why things happen the way they do.

Comment: Fun fact: I keep getting up-votes but no answers.

Comment: I think the fcc that you mention is the key. I can imagine it in my head, but hard to explain. Try drawing an fcc crystal on paper and plotting the 110 plane - it will cut diagonally across the side of the face-centered cell. By extrapolation, I would also expect cleavage on 101 and 011 planes.

Comment: According to mindat.org it has perfect cleavage on {001}. Do the curly brackets include those planes mentioned by you?

Comment: Yes. So where did you get the (110) from?

Comment: My mineralogy professor who has a PhD in geology... Don't ask

Answer (score 5):

I think the commenters have identified the issue. Halite does not have perfect cleavage along the {110} plane. As recorded in [Mindat](http://www.webmineral.com/data/Halite.shtml#.WV40FlGQxpg), Halite has perfect cleavage alone {100}, {010}, and {001}. This makes sense, as Halite is a cubic mineral (fcc), these are the planes you would expect it to cleave on.

Comment: [This does control the cleavage direction but there are other cubic minerals where the ion sizes and charge mean the cleavage is stronger in different directions. A good example is fluorite, calcium fluoride, which often forms cubic-shaped crystals but has octahedral cleavage.](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/a/10634/6031)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqmOm.png from https://aflow.org/prototype-encyclopedia/ABCD_cF16_216_c_d_b_a.html